# Unexpected behaviour of pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels

Tags: python, pandas

I have noticed an unexpected result when resetting the level values in a `pandas.MultiIndex`. The minimal working example I have found to reproduce the problem is as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

numbers = np.arange(11).astype(str)
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A'],numbers])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[0], columns=columns, dtype=float)
print(df.columns)
```

returns

```
MultiIndex([('A',  '0'),
            ('A',  '1'),
            ('A',  '2'),
            ('A',  '3'),
            ('A',  '4'),
            ('A',  '5'),
            ('A',  '6'),
            ('A',  '7'),
            ('A',  '8'),
            ('A',  '9'),
            ('A', '10')],
           )
```

Notice how all values on the second level are strings of integers. I have tried to replace them with the respective integers by using the `set_levels` method:

```py
numbers = df.columns.get_level_values(1).astype(int)
df.columns = df.columns.set_levels(numbers, level=1)
print(df.columns)
```

To my surprise, the result looks as follows:

```
MultiIndex([('A',  0),
            ('A',  1),
            ('A',  3),
            ('A',  4),
            ('A',  5),
            ('A',  6),
            ('A',  7),
            ('A',  8),
            ('A',  9),
            ('A', 10),
            ('A',  2)],
           )
```

The values on the second level now are in a different order. What am I missing here? How can I actually replace the integer strings with the respective integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit confusing but it's not a surprise and this is the expected behavior. I slightly modified your example:

```
numbers = np.arange(11).astype(str)
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A'],numbers])
df = pd.DataFrame(columns.codes, index=['Lvl0', 'Lvl1'], columns=columns)
print(df)

# Output:
      A                               
      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8   9 10
Lvl0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  # internal codes for level 0
Lvl1  0  1  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  2  # internal codes for level 1
```

When you create your MultiIndex (here, with numbers as string), Pandas creates internal codes (for indexing, sorting, etc) associated to the labels but in the lexicographical order in your case:

```
# labels: '0' < '1' < '10' < '2' < '3' < '4' < '5' < '6' < '7' < '8' < '9'
# codes:   0  <  1  <   2  <  3  <  4  <  5  <  6  <  7  <  8  <  9  < 10

>>> df.columns.codes
FrozenList([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2]])

>>> df.columns.is_monotonic_increasing
False  # because it's not lexicographically ordered

>>> df.sort_index(axis=1)  # lexicographical sort
      A                               
      0  1 10  2  3  4  5  6  7  8   9
Lvl0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
Lvl1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
```

As human, you use `labels` to access your columns but `Pandas` uses `codes` behind the scene to optimize indexing and maintain order.

In the second part of your code, you convert the `labels` from string to int and set level. However, you don't sort the index so the previous order (given by codes) are still maintained:

```
# labels:  0  <  1  <   2  <  3  <  4  <  5  <  6  <  7  <  8  <  9  < 10
# codes:   0  <  1  <   2  <  3  <  4  <  5  <  6  <  7  <  8  <  9  < 10

>> df.columns.codes
FrozenList([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2]])

>>> df.columns.is_monotonic_increasing
False

>>> df.sort_index(axis=1)  # numbering sort
      A                               
      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9   10
Lvl0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0
Lvl1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9   10
```

As you can see, you lost correct values. **You have to sort your columns before**:

```
>>> df  # with '0', '1', '2', etc
      A                               
      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8   9 10
Lvl0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0
Lvl1  0  1  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  2

>>> df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
      A                               
      0  1 10  2  3  4  5  6  7  8   9
Lvl0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
Lvl1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10

# set_levels(...)

>>> df  # with 0, 1, 2, etc
      A                               
      0  1  10  2  3  4  5  6  7  8   9 
Lvl0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
Lvl1  0  1   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10

>>> df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
      A                               
      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8   9  10
Lvl0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
Lvl1  0  1  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10   2  # now values and columns are well aligned.
```

Comment: I hope I was clear enough for you to understand the problem :-)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, that's what I needed. The documentation for the `set_levels` method is unfortunately quite sparse regarding this aspect.

Comment: So after I have to sort the row index twice this way, it might be easier to rebuild the whole index right away with the correct values, right?

Comment: You only need to sort once before set_levels to ensure all codes are well aligned. It's really not obvious even for me (multiindex is a pain!). Remember labels are only for you to show your dataframe. This is the same mechanism for ordered categoricaldtype.